# ReportViewer Table

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

Any idea how can i accomplish the next scenario in a rdlc?
I have some rows (`PrimaryKey`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`)
I want to display a table like this:

```
Labels of my fields    | FirstRowValues      | SecondRowValues   |
___________________________________________________________________
Label for Primary key  | PrimaryKey1.Value   | PrimaryKey2.Value |  
Label of col1          | Col1.Value(row 1)   | Col1.Value(row 2) |  
Label of col2          | Col2.Value(row 2)   | Col2.Value(row 2) |
```

In other words, instead of having my database rows being repeated on diferrent rdlc rows, i would like to have them repeated on different columns.

I hope i was clear enough about what i'm looking for.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Matrix control (instead of the Table), or use PIVOT and do it in your database query.

I think are using the VS report designer, not SSRS (SSRS does not create RDLCs that can be viewed in the VS 2008 ReportViewer control).

Answer (score 0):

10x 4 ur response, but i wasn't looking for that. Solved my issue by using a matrix with a column group by expression "1", and then added multiple rows on this group. Not the most elegant solution, but works.